# EF6 Set Relation Table With Different Column Name Using Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

I am trying to make n-n relation with rel table using Fluent API but i am messed up with inconsistent column names.

I have `Service` and `Feature` objects simply like this:

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public int FirmID { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    [Key]
    public int FeatureID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I have already defined relation table:

```
ServiceFeature
--------------
ServiceID
FeatureID
```

Normally I can map like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Features)
    .WithMany(e => e.Services)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("ServiceFeature").MapLeftKey("ServiceID").MapRightKey("FeatureID"));
```

But here is the problem: `ServiceID` from `ServiceFeature` is actually `FirmID` from `Service` and I couldn't figure out how to map it like this.

Is there any way to define column names for each table?

Comment: may be `Map(m => m.ToTable("ServiceFeature").MapRightKey("ServiceID").MapLeftKey("FeatureID")` (invert Right and Left)

Comment: But ServiceID is actually FirmID from Service

Comment: you mean your database is in production with real data ? In this case you will have (additionaly) to use some sql to rename columns.

Comment: @tschmit007 yep. I used codefirst from database and try to configure the relations manually. I can not have the permissions to altering.

Comment: then you'll have to invert values in the columns

Comment: @tschmit007 unfotunately I can not change anything about db. I try to change mapping.